# Cordova plugin cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine cannot show image

Tags: image, cordova, wkwebview, hybrid

I am using Cordova Hybird with ExtJS. I am migrating from `UIWebView` to `WKWebView` by `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine`. However, this cannot show image from photo library or camera.

Even I solved null origin problem, tried other plugins like `cordova-plugin-migrate-localstorage`, `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine` & `cordova-plugin-migrate-localstorage`, `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr`, etc. I still cannot shoe image after I chose from photo library.

What should I do to show image correctly? Please share sample code if any.

Comment: What's your InterceptRemoteRequests preference for cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr ?

Comment: I set "all" for cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr. BTW, I used cordova-plugin-ionic-migrate-localstorage with normalizeURL() then solved the problem. Thanks Eric!